# Remove xml tag when its attribute is empty using mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have following xml content in a column,

```
<Certification name="ACT" type=""/>
<Certification name="CERTIFIED PEDIATRIC NURSE" type="Certification"/>
<Certification name="LICENSED VOCATIONAL NURSE (LVN)" type="License"/>
```

My question is when I find empty in 'type' atrribute , that single tag should be eleminated.

for example I need output like follows,

```
  <Certification name="CERTIFIED PEDIATRIC NURSE" type="Certification"/>
  <Certification name="LICENSED VOCATIONAL NURSE (LVN)" type="License"/>
```

In the above output empty 'type' attribute has been removed.

So could anyone suggest how to do it using sql query?

Comment: Is this to be a permanent change or just changing the result returned in a `SELECT` (but leaving the data as-is within the table)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this...

```
DECLARE @xml as table(xmlData xml)

insert into @xml(xmlData)
select '<Certification name="ACT" type=""/><Certification name="CERTIFIED PEDIATRIC NURSE" type="Certification"/><Certification name="LICENSED VOCATIONAL NURSE (LVN)" type="License"/>'

SELECT xmlData.query('/Certification[@type!=""]') as filteredXml
FROM   @xml T
```

As you've got it already in a table column you can just use the last select statement substituting @xml and xmlData with your table name and table field respectively